# what is the difference between assertQueue and send To Queue in RabbitMq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have found Example for Sending String in rabittMq and Receiving from the queue but  I am not clear about about these methods - **assertQueue** , **sendToQueue**

**send.js**

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {

              var q = 'hello';
                var msg = 'Hello World! - '+i;

                ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});                    
                ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
                console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
  });
  setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 1000);
});
```

**receive.js**

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {          //amqp://localhost
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: true});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 28):

From your example,

[**assertQueue**](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_assertQueue) checks for "hello" queue, if it doesn't exist then it will create one.

[**sendToQueue**](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_sendToQueue) put a message onto "hello" queue.

Comment: Thanks for this. Nowhere in the docs does it say that if the queue doesn't exist it creates one. Weird...

Answer (score 4):

**assertQueue** is an **declaration of queue**  and **sendToQueue** is **pushing your message in the queue**

**To be noted** : Declaring a queue is idempotent - it will only be created if it doesn't exist already